# What does "get out nails done " mean?

Tags: phrase-meaning

I have a letter from a native English speaker. A sentence of that is as follows:

"We were only going to ***get out nails done*** today and go to a couple of stores and home."

I have searched google for "get out nails done" and I found lots of examples. I can understand that it is about "nail art" or "nails decoration" but the structure of the phrase "get out nails done" looks strange for me.

I have searched "get out" and "get out something done" but I found nothing related. Sure I found something about "get something done" but I couldn't find anything about "get out something done". So I am looking for a good explanation about "get out nails done" meaning and structure.

Comment: I think that it's a typo. It should be "get OUR nails done" instead of "get OUT nails done". Notice that the letter "r" is by the letter "t" in the keyboard. You have already found what "get something done" means, you just have to replace "something" by "OUR nails".

Comment: It can't be a typo. You can search google for "get out nails done" then you have a lot of examples of that phrase.

Comment: Goggle returns only 130 hits. Is that what you call "lots of examples"?

Comment: "Get *out* nails done" has to be a typo, otherwise it would make some sense to a native British English speaker, which it absolutely does not. "t" and "r" are right next to each other on a qwerty keyboard, it almost certainly should be "our" (which makes sense). Also, as this is a letter from an individual and not a published piece of writing, the best person to ask would be the author. Voting to close.

Comment: My friend is from United States. She is  not British. I have searched google for ""get out nails done" and google wrote "About 70,600 results (0.29 seconds)". This is a lot of examples. isn't it?

Comment: It's a lot of examples of people making the same basic typo, yes. There are 120,000 results for the correct phrase "get our nails done". Most notably, there are absolutely NO results for your incorrect phrase found in literature. Google searches everything - blog posts, sites like this - basically all your search proves is that people who get their nails done can't type. Probably because of their massive false nails on the keyboard.

Comment: Maybe you are true. So I am going to ask my friend about that. Anyway I should thank you for your attention.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the given example contains an obvious typo., and no existing examples were in the question.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is simply a typo for **"get our nails done"**, which is an extremely common phrase - to get (one's) nails done. Perhaps you thought it was some kind of idiom, but no such idiom exists.

Comment: I guess you are wrong. would you please read all of the comments.

Comment: When you perform a simple google search for "get out nails done" it returns hits which are spelling variations of the phrase. Check for yourself. You will see that it returns hits for "get **our** nails done",  "get **your** nails done", etc, even though you searched for "get out nails done".That is why there is a high number of hits - the algorithm is assuming you typed the phrase incorrectly.

Comment: Now I guess you are right. I am going to ask my friend.

Comment: Just to offer further evidence: https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=get+our+nails+done&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cget%20our%20nails%20done%3B%2Cc0. There are zero entries for "get out nails done"